# User Flow/Entrance Paths in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I noticed within my entrance path data in Google Analytics that I can only see instances where certain pages are landing pages, thus leading to less data than I would like. I did see the Navigation Summary but that looked like only 24% of data showed up and did not sum to 100% when including the exit rate from the site as I tested it with 2 pages. Is there another way for me to see accurate numbers on where people are going to after entering a specific page?

Answer (score 0):

You can select until 500 rows with combobox 'show rows' in Navigation Summary report.